# Proposed FAQ content (final draft)

Tags: discussion, scope, faq-page

Based on the work done at [Content for the main site FAQ first block (What kind of questions can I ask here)?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1572/104), I'm proposing to update our FAQ page as follows (with corresponding changes to the About page as well. Please vote on this question to indicate whether you agree or think more work is needed. If more work, please indicate what needs doing.

---

### What kind of questions can I ask here?

Genealogy and Family History is a question and answer site for experts in, or people interested in, [genealogy and family history](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/on-and-off-topic-questions-what-is-genealogy-and-family-history). With your help, we're building a comprehensive library of answers to questions about genealogy and family history.

If your question is about:

- Starting your research or improving your methodology
- Finding a source or understanding how to use it
- Documenting or presenting what you’ve learned
- Breaking down brick-walls in your family tree
- Using technology to support your research

and it is not about:

- Locating identifiable living individuals
- Which genealogy software or website is “the best”
- Developing genealogy software
- Celebrity or [biblical genealogy](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/)
- [General history](https://history.stackexchange.com/)

then you’re in the right place. We welcome questions at all levels, and you can expect a range of answers from very basic to highly technical, depending on how you phrase your question. The community tends to respond better to questions that show you have already done some research (at least used a search engine or consulted a dictionary) before asking for help.

Subjective questions are allowed, as long as they are on-topic and constructive, but subjective does not mean “anything goes”. Remember that answers should explain 'why' and 'how', and be backed up either with facts and references, or experiences that happened to you personally.

Updated: As nobody has dissented, I've updated https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/about and https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/faq.

Comment: I'm excited. We're finally growing up with mods and a customized FAQ.

Comment: I want to compliment ColeValleyGirl - about and FAQ are excellent.

Comment: @Duncan, thanks, but most of the work was done by the community -- I just summarised it at the end.