# On- and off-topic questions: Application of technology

Tags: discussion, scope

As mentioned at [On- and off-topic questions: an attempt to reach consensus](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1372/104) (please read first) this is one of a set of questions attempting to reach consensus on the scope for this site.

This question focuses on questions relating to the

### Application of technology

i.e. the use of hardware, software, websites and other science and technology specifically to support genealogy and family history activities.

Please up-vote answers you believe are on-topic, down-vote answers you believe are off topic and add your own suggestions for what should be in or out (with your view made clear).

Related questions:

[What is "Genealogy," "Family History," and "Microhistory"?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1373/104)

[On- and off-topic questions: Research processes and methodologies](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1387/104)

[On- and off-topic questions: Locating records and documents](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1399/104)

[On- and off-topic questions: Interpreting records](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1403/104)

[On- and off-topic questions: Researching specific ancestors](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1410/104)

[On- and off-topic questions: Other specialist related topics](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1418/104)

Answer (score 5):

Data exchange formats and standards (GEDcom, FHISO etc.)

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Answer (score 4):

Can software package X do Y

- ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic
- PolyGeo view: On-topic but asker should show research and preferably testing as background

Comment: I don't see how this question can meet the adequate prior research criterion. If it does, then it's "How can I ..." below.

Comment: @Fortiter, there are some things you can't tell about a package until you own it, however much research you do -- sometimes you just have to ask somebody.

Comment: But does the somebody that you ask have to be this site? Surely the answer to these questions is RTFM (or perhaps "Have you heard of Google?")

Comment: @Fortiter, If you *really* can't get the answer other than by asking somebody who already uses the package, can you ask here? The manual for the software package I use, for example, doesn't tell you if it's possible to organise a report in a specific way -- you have to try combinations of options, which is difficult if you don't own the package, or ask somebody who does own it. Actually, you can't even get the manual if you don't own the package. (In truth you'd probably go to the User Group, and I remember a question elsewhere about whether we want to compete with specialist user groups).

Comment: Better is the "How do I do X with Y package/website" question. If you can't, someone will answer that and might give an alternative way to do it with the package or with something else.

Answer (score 4):

Use of DNA testing for genealogy/family history purposes

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic
PolyGeo view: On-topic

Comment: Again: for genealogical purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Use of specific genealogy and family history software products and web sites/technologies

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Comment: Yes! Absolutely!

Answer (score 2):

How do I do X with package/website Y?

- ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic
- PolyGeo view: On-topic but asker should show research and preferably testing as background

Answer (score 2):

Establishing criteria for choosing software products/web sites e.g. [What are the key features in genealogical software that will help me future proof my research?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1821/104)

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Comment: How about an example of what you mean?

Comment: @lkessler Added one.

Answer (score 2):

Use of GIS technology (Geographic Information Systems) in a genealogical/family history context

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Comment: Only within a genealogical context. There already is a GIS stackexchange site: http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @lkessler edited to clarify

Answer (score 2):

Digital preservation **as it specifically applies to** genealogy and family history

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic (General digital preservation questions would be off-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Use of other technologies to specifically support genealogy and family history

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Comment: Too broad to be useful if we list GIS as a specific. This becomes "Misc, etc"

Comment: @Fortiter, true, but I didn't want to exclude other technologies implicitly if they have genealogical application

Answer (score 0):

Use of mobile technologies **specifically applied to** genealogy and family history

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic (General use of mobile technologies would be off-topic)

Comment: I am not clear on how this is different than the software packages one necessarily as for example there is an App for translating languages by pointing your camera phone at it.. but is that on topic or because it is used for translation it would?

Answer (score -4):

What is the best software product/website to do X?

- ColeValleyGirl view: Off-topic (Likely to generate lists and opinions, so be not constructive)
- PolyGeo view: Off-topic (Likely to generate lists and opinions, so be not constructive)

Answer (score -4):

I'm developing a software product to support X genealogical activity -- what features should it support

ColeValleyGirl view: Off-topic (Likely to generate lists and opinions, so be not constructive)

Comment: I suspect that a couple of my questions will be mis-represented under this heading. They were not related to commercial products but did try to solicit answers to solve genuine problems. There is nothing wrong with responses comprising opinions (anyone expecting absolute answers is going to be disappointed), and having a list of elements in an answer is certainly not unconstructive.