# On- and off-topic questions: Research processes and methodologies

Tags: discussion, scope

As mentioned at [On- and off-topic questions: an attempt to reach consensus](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1372/104) (please read first) this is one of a set of questions attempting to reach consensus on the scope for this site.

This question focuses on questions relating to the

### Research processes and methodologies

i.e. advice and guidance on best practice when carrying out genealogy and family history research

Please up-vote answers you believe are on-topic, down-vote answers you believe are off topic and add your own suggestions for what should be in or out (with your view made clear).

Related questions:

[What is "Genealogy," "Family History," and "Microhistory"?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1373/104)

[On- and off-topic questions: Application of technology](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1374/104)

[On- and off-topic questions: Locating records and documents](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1399/104)

[On- and off-topic questions: Interpreting records](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1403/104)

[On- and off-topic questions: Researching specific ancestors](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1410/104)

[On- and off-topic questions: Other specialist related topics](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1418/104)

Comment: I had to upvote the question to keep the software happy that I was not only voting on answers!

Answer (score 3):

Getting started/next steps with family history and genealogy research, such as:

- Must I use a software program to record my family history?
- Who do I research first?
- How do I plan a field trip?

These should be specific questions about one aspect of the research process. Questions such as: "I want to learn my family history. How do I do it?" are too broad to be answerable (even if they are on-topic).

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Comment: These questions need to be specific. "I want to find my family genealogy. Where do I start?" is waaaay to broad. NARQ. This is stressed in FAQ section two sentence four (I know this one by heart): "If you can imagine an *entire book* that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: @Luke, I think that's a good question/bad question aspect -- it must be on-topic for a newbie to seek advice on the first steps, as long as they do it with a specific question.

Comment: I'm not opposed to the questions of newbies, but this one just came across as very broad. Perhaps you could clarify this a bit?

Comment: @Luke, edited. Better?

Comment: +1 Much better.

Answer (score 2):

Techniques and terminology when working with sources, information and evidence, including citing sources

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Answer (score 2):

Applying the Genealogical Proof Standard, Inferential Genealogy and other best practice guidelines and advanced techniques

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Answer (score 2):

Organising and tracking research activities and results

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Answer (score 2):

Working with others, including interviewing relatives, working with family history societies, and collaborating with other researchers

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Answer (score 2):

Document and artefact handling and preservation

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Answer (score 1):

How do I best document and present what I’ve learned

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Answer (score 1):

How should I handle ethics and legalities issues (e.g. copyright, privacy, sensitivity)

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Comment: Legal issues are usually off-topic on Stack Exchange because of legal concerns. ["We are not lawyers, we do not know the details of your situation and the law of the country you live in. Hire a lawyer."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19886/192187)

Comment: Yes but ... While I support the idea that we disclaim the giving of any legal advice there remain quasi-legal matters of ethics and propriety that deserve consideration.

Comment: @Luke, copyright and privacy are both likely to come up, and both are legal issues -- we need at least to be able to say that they are legal issues.

Answer (score 1):

Working with personal or place names, including naming standards and conventions

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Answer (score 1):

Calculating/describing the relationship between two individuals in a tree

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Answer (score 0):

How do I apply genealogical numbering systems

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Answer (score 0):

How do I measure the progress of my research

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic