# On- and off-topic: Ethics?

Tags: discussion, scope

Prompted by [How to help adoptee find her father without outing him?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/14549/1006)

Is this kind of answerable as a case study for what are good ethical practices for genealogists? Should such questions be on- or off-topic?

Comment: I would be more comfortable with the question if it was an abstract case study. https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1389/6485

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this question is about the ethics. It technically is on topic.

But this question bothers me too much. Because, I still think a living person is a distinct possibility.  I have provided an answer to the question with my thoughts.

Comment: I'd upvote this several times if I could.

Comment: It bugs me, too, which is why I wanted a discussion.

Comment: @JanMurphy I think we can address the ethics without keeping the detail?

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Removing details would also make the question of more general interest.

Comment: I can't say that the question bothers me. I did write up an answer, but then decided that it was way too close to suggesting doing unethical things. I like your answer, @lkessler.

Answer (score 1):

I think [How to help adoptee find her father without outing him?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/14549) is a very difficult question to answer, but its asker has clearly taken pains to make clear that it is not about locating an identifiable living individual (he must remain unidentifiable on our site even if the asker and their cousin are able to identify him), and that they are making every effort to respect the privacy of any living individuals involved, as well as our Privacy Policy, while at the same time trying to assist their cousin to start discovering half of her genealogy.

My view is that the question is on-topic.