# On- and off-topic questions: Locating records and documents

Tags: discussion, scope

As mentioned at [On- and off-topic questions: an attempt to reach consensus](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1372/104) (please read first) this is one of a set of questions attempting to reach consensus on the scope for this site.

This question focuses on questions relating to

### Locating records and documents

i.e. advice and guidance on locating specific records and information

Please up-vote answers you believe are on-topic, down-vote answers you believe are off topic and add your own suggestions for what should be in or out (with your view made clear).

Related questions:

[What is "Genealogy," "Family History," and "Microhistory"?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1373/104)

[On- and off-topic questions: Application of technology](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1374/104)

[On- and off-topic questions: Research processes and methodologies](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1387/104)

[On- and off-topic questions: Interpreting records](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1403/104)

[On- and off-topic questions: Researching specific ancestors](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1410/104)

[On- and off-topic questions: Other specialist related topics](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1418/104)

Answer (score 4):

How can I find records about X event in P place around time T

On-topic:

ColeValleyGirl,  Fortiter, Luke, CRSouser, PolyGeo

Off-topic:

Comment: Edited as an example of an alternative voting system to illustrate my suggestion elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

How can I locate a named record/document

On-topic:

ColeValleyGirl, Luke, CRSouser, PolyGeo

Off-Topic:

Answer (score 2):

How can I find information about a specific topic

Example question: [How did the lives of Worcestershire nail-makers change 1840-1880?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1902/104)

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic as long as the topic itself is within the scope of this site

Comment: Not a helpful category.

Comment: @Fortiter, http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1902/104 was what I had in mind when I generated this category.

Comment: Making me vote against my own question is "nasty"! This does show the importance of real examples in defining categories.

Comment: @fortiter, I didn't mean to be nasty. It's a questions that I genuinely think is on-topic (perhaps because it's relevant to my ancestors as well).

Comment: It was meant as a flippant comment. I am not all offended. My genuine concern is that obviously I think the specific question is good but I did not recognise it in that very general descriptive category. I will think about an edit.

Comment: @Fortiter -- thanks. I wish more people would edit -- these should be **our** categories.

Answer (score -1):

How to find *modern* records for one's own self-interest:

Example: [How Can I Investigate if I Inherited a Real Estate from My Relative?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/7960/how-can-i-investigate-if-i-inherited-a-real-estate-from-my-relative)

On-Topic:

Off-Topic:

- Jan Murphy: Looking to see if you are in a will of a recently deceased person would also reveal the other heirs.  Does this violate our policy of not aiding people to track down living people?

  [Finding details of recent Will in California?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/7960/how-can-i-investigate-if-i-inherited-a-real-estate-from-my-relative)
- Helen Wright
- CRSouser (See Comment below)

Comment: I am having trouble on exactly how to interpret this one. I agree with @JanMurphy's comment, but also it is about tracking down say the secondary family of a recently deceased individual I think we need to watch out for. So maybe update the rules to state no possibly living or having deceased in the last 20 years (1 generation rule) as I could use this recent info to locate a living individual.. even if deceased.. which could then be used for personal gain, pursue inheritence, child support, etc.