# On- and off-topic questions: Other specialist related topics

Tags: discussion, scope

As mentioned at [On- and off-topic questions: an attempt to reach consensus](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1372/104) (please read first) this is one of a set of questions attempting to reach consensus on the scope for this site.

This question focuses on questions relating to

### Other specialist related topics

i.e. advice and guidance on topics generally considered to be related to genealogy and family history

Please up-vote answers you believe are on-topic, down-vote answers you believe are off topic and add your own suggestions for what should be in or out (with your view made clear).

Related questions:

- [What is "Genealogy," "Family History," and "Microhistory"?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1373/104)
- [On- and off-topic questions: Application of technology](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1374/104)
- [On- and off-topic questions: Research processes and methodologies](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1387/104)
- [On- and off-topic questions: Locating records and documents](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1399/104)
- [On- and off-topic questions: Interpreting records](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1403/104)
- [On- and off-topic questions: Researching specific ancestors](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1410/104)
- [Is royal genealogy on- or off-topic? (Country irrelevant)](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2016)

Answer (score 5):

Origin and meaning of surnames

- ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic
- PolyGeo view: On-topic but often low value - better to veer asker towards finding where their ancestors came from using genealogical research methods

Comment: Including surname distribution (as an aid to locating origins and records) might 'add value'

Answer (score 4):

Heraldry

ColeValleyGirl view: on-topic

Comment: Discussed in more detail in another post: http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/does-heraldry-as-a-general-topic-belong-on-this-site

Answer (score 4):

Government policies relative to genealogists (e.g. pricing, access to government records)

ColeValleyGirl view: Undecided.

Comment: Questions about what is or isn't available to genealogists per government policy is definitely on-topic.  However, discussions about how to change such policies is not.

Answer (score 4):

Academic and other studies of genealogists and their networks

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic

Comment: I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: @JanMurphy http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/317/104 is an example

Answer (score 2):

Discussions about the origins or etymology of given names (note: surnames have already been discussed).

- Jan Murphy: Allowable as part of a discussion of a solvable problem.  Follow the rule in dont-ask which says general "chatty" discussions are off-topic.
- PolyGeo:  Allowable as part of a discussion of a solvable problem.  For example: [Why might name Ferdinando be found in early 17th century Cornwall baptisms?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9206)

Answer (score 1):

Genealogy of Royalty, Celebrities and other Famous People

- ColeValleyGirl view: **Off-topic** (unless it's being used to illustrate a research process question)
- PolyGeo view: **On-topic** (as long as the Privacy Policy is observed)

Comment: I have a person in my database whose case illustrates both of these situations at the same time (might be related to someone in my research *and* is an interesting research process question).  The only other exception I would make is asking a question related to a person featured in one of the celebrity-based TV shows like *Who Do You Think You Are*, where the question is a follow-up about a record group or research process that was mentioned in the show.  On the other hand, WDYTYA and other shows have the celebrity's permission to go digging and we do not.

Answer (score 1):

Ethnicity calculations and assessments (other than by DNA)

- ColeValleyGirl view: Off-topic
- Jan Murphy: Off-topic (I would also include assessments that include DNA, unless the question involves working a specific genealogical problem)

Answer (score -1):

Entitlement to wear a specific tartan (or other lineage-specific clothing)

ColeValleyGirl view: On-topic (if heraldry is)

Comment: Expand to include lineage society qualifications? - didn't see that mentioned elsewhere, and seems to be along the same lines.

Comment: @bgwiehle Not sure about that -- at least qualifying for a lineage society needs some genealogical input, whereas wearing a specific tartan almost never does.

Answer (score -2):

Modern naming practices, e.g. Choose a name for my baby, or How do I change my name?

ColeValleyGirl view: Off-topic

Answer (score -4):

Appearance or health-characteristics determined by genealogy e.g. I'm red-headed; am I Scottish. Or: my grand-father had X; will I inherit it?

ColeValleyGirl view: Off-topic

Comment: However, I think genetics as related to genealogical determination of biological parantage, and similar characteristic among family members as a clue to determining relationships would be on topic.

Comment: @Lkessler is that the same as http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/1381/104?

Comment: Yes. That's the same thing.

Answer (score -4):

History trivia and crossword puzzle questions

ColeValleyGirl view: Off-topic

Answer (score -4):

Discussions about Biblical genealogy

Comment: Pointing to the FAQ section two, line one here: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: What if my hobby and research is biblical genealogy? Do the questions come here, or is some other StackExchange site better?

Comment: Stack Exchange does not guarantee to have a site for every question. However, in this case, [Biblical Hermeneutics](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/) is your site.

Comment: @πLuke - 14 search results there for "genealogy"!