# What do we want to do with the tag "online"? Should we get rid of it?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

This https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3296/6485 suggestion seemed to slip through without being implemented -- should we take it forward?

[online](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) seems to be used for a grab-bag of purposes -- finding and relocating records online, publishing online including ethics questions, message boards, online tree software,  synching online and offline trees...

Note: the tag has no wiki, so it's not surprising it's a grab bag.

Updated to add: I'll leave this here for a week to get reaction, and then act on the most upvoted answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand what having [online](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) buys us. Will people follow such a tag? I'm happy to see it go.

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be no one wanting to retain it so the [online](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) tag has now been burninated.