# Community Eval finished

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

The first Genealogy and Family History community evaluation is now finished. I would like to thank every user who participated in it.

Over the seven days of the evaluation, 120 reviews were performed by 13 reviewers.

*Note: Heretofore the term "question" shall refer to both the question and the answers of a post unless otherwise specified.*

---

This graph was inspired by [this graph by Badp](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6859). It shows the total score of each question (`#excellent - #needs improvement`), how many votes of each type each question received, and the total amounts of each vote cast.

[image]

---

The chart below shows how different types of questions were reviewed on average.

[image]

As you can see, questions about the application of technology and best practices were overall positively reviewed, but questions about researching specific ancestors were overall negatively reviewed. *Categories taken from [Analysis of questions to date](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1332/56)*

---

The next chart shows the correlation between the questions' score (here referring to the up/down-voting of the question alone) and how they were reviewed in the community evaluation.

[image]

There seems to be no direct correlation between how questions were reviewed and their score by voting. In fact, the two highest voted questions received slightly less-than-average reviews.

---

This graph shows the distribution of different types of questions-- pretty straightforward.

[image]

---

This graph shows the correlation between how the various questions were reviewed.

[image]

The questions that received better reviews (on the left) had mostly "excellent" reviews and a few "satisfactory" reviews (which increase as you go further right). There were no "Needs Improvement" reviews on the top three. This clearly shows that most users have a unified concept of what makes a good question. However, as we look at the right-hand side of the graph, we see that there's more disagreement on what is a not-so-great question.

---

### Questions:

[What is the meaning of the "TAX" stamp on a ship's manifest?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2609/56)

[1935 residence in the 1940 census](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2575/56)

[Financial preconditions on Jews for marriage in early 19th century in Germany?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2784/56)

[Identifying Blenkinsopp-Leaton family photos](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2782/56)

[Can anyone decipher the comment above Louis' name on this 1940 census record?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2470/56)

[Copyright Issues with Content Providers](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2615/56)

[What is the correct word for Step siblings?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2520/56)

[Finding Passenger Lists for Irish immigrants to USA 1923-1925?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2826/56)

[What factors should I consider when choosing a DNA-testing service?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2472/56)

[Locating parents and siblings of someone born in Oklahoma (1903)?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2517/56)

---

### TL;DR

Nine of the ten questions were reviewed overall positively and only one was reviewed negatively overall. Everyone was mostly in agreement about what is a good question, but there were some disagreement about what is a low quality question.

---

Again, thank you to everyone who helped in this GFH community evaluation. Your faithful dedication is helping us to make Genealogy and Family History.SE a better site. If you would like any other statistics on our evaluation, just let me know and I'll see what I can do.

*P.S. If it is not already apparent, I like graphs.*

Comment: Ok, this is cool.

Comment: @Luke Thanks for the writeup. Can you elaborate a little what you mean by _positively reviewed_ and _negatively reviewed_ for the first chart? What is the scale on the positive/negative spectrum, and how were the values calculated per question? Also, was anything asked about what made questions better or worse than others?

Comment: In answer to your first question, a positive review is when you click the 'excellent' button, a negative review is when you click the 'needs improvement' button, and the 'satisfactory' button is neutral. The formula that used is `(#excellent - #needsImprovement)/#totalReviews`. In answer to your last question, the only question asked was to select one of the four orange buttons.

Comment: Good job. Can you say more on reviewers (eg was everybody invited to review and only 13 bothered?) and questions to review (eg was it random across all questions?).

Comment: Everybody with 15+ rep was eligible to review. Questions were chosen randomly. These questions must be open, have at least one answer, and be asked 30-40 days ago.

Answer (score 2):

I did hunt around the other sites for comparison and I do want to congratulate you on your presenting of the data. You seem to have done a much more complete job than most.

Since you like graphs you might check out [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6858/community-evaluation-results-2-february-2013). It shows the questions and the distribution. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166397/can-we-see-the-results-of-our-community-evaluation) mentions there is an automated metapost somewhere. Is there?

Comment: You're looking at it. :P This is currently the only public announcement of the presentation of the data, AFAIK. Doing site evaluations within a review queue is a new thing (I think this was the first one. ever). I'm pretty sure the devs are planning something automated. It should be public in six to eight weeks.